# Can't use create_async() with WRL WinRT component

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, wrl

I want to write a WinRT component with async support using WRL, but I found `create_async()` is undefined even I included the `ppltask.h` and `using namespace concurrency`
How to create a background task with WRL pattern?

My function is like:

```
HRESULT GetStreamAsync([out, retval] IAsyncOperation<IRRandomAccessStream*>** operation);
```

I also try to use `IThreadPoolStatics->RunAsync()`, but seems it only can be used in case of `IAsyncAction` and without return value. Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`concurrency::create_async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750102.aspx) is only usable in C++/CX (this may not be expressly stated in the documentation, but all of the possible return types are hat types, indicating it is only usable in C++/CX).

WRL includes the [`Microsoft::WRL::AsyncBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244878.aspx) base class template, which you can derive from to implement asynchronous operations using C++ and WRL.

I don't know of a canonical implementation that wraps [`std::future`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920539.aspx) or [`concurrency::task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750113.aspx), but you can find an example of an implementation in the Boost-licensed [CxxReflect library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920539.aspx) (search for `async_operation_base` and `task_based_async_operation`).