# Class not registered exception when calling a WinRT compontent after migrating to VS2013.4

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a HTML5 application, that contains a .winmd component used for file system operations (sqlite, zip archives and so on).

After I upgraded to 2013.4 this component suddenly stopped working. Javascript still sees all the classes and function, but when I attempt to call any of them I get "WinRT: Class not registered" exception.

Full VS reinstall didn't help. Neither did upgrading to community version. This behavior is reproduced on both desktop (8.1pro) and laptop (win8.1 single language)

I spent 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong and I found that it fails as soon as component includes any asyncronous activity (like await/async or just Task.Delay(100))

So my concern is... What's going on? Where I was wrong and what can I do?

Right now installing 2015 preview. If I roll back to 2013.3 using system restore, project works fine, but VS gets in semi-broken state, and there is no link on a MS website to download previous version.

If what I say doesn't make any sense, i may upload a file with a simpliest possible VS solution to reproduce a problem. But in brief it's as simple as:

```
namespace NSUtil {
  public sealed class Test{
    public static IAsyncOperation<string> DoSomething () {
      return Task<string>.Run(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "";
      }).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
  }
}
```

and as soon as I call `NSUtil.Test.doSomething()` from javascript, i get `WinRTError: Class not registered` exception.

So the question is.... What's wrong with me/my pc/my vs installation/microsoft developers?

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue occurring on two machines, one dev machine through the IDE and one build machine through command line. No solution at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: No solution so far. Rolled back to vs2013.3. Sigh

Comment: Async functions shouldn't return anything, at least not in JS. Is there a reason you're returning something in the first line of `DoSomething` ? Stumbled upon these resources, they may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890841/cant-use-create-async-with-wrl-winrt-component?rq=1
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2014/11/10/wrl-implementations-of-ivector-and-iasyncoperation.aspx

Comment: Use try catch in your C# class and get exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is: one should put in package.appxmanifest following lines:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyNS.MyClass1" ThreadingModel="both" />
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyNS.MyClass2" ThreadingModel="both" />
      ...
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyNS.MyClassN" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

where `MyNS.MyClass{N}` are all classes, exposed to WinRT.
For some weird reason VS2013.4 doesn't do it on its own, so I had to do it on my own

Answer (score 0):

check your application permission and run as admin vs to use javaScript classes or change your project file location to an other drive. in windows 8.1 sometimes application need Admin permission to use files  and classes.